# Netbeans project properties doesn't list my remote platform

Tags: java, netbeans, raspberry-pi

I am trying to develop a java SE application on a Raspberry Pi, using NetBeans. I have created a platform for the Pi using the Platform Manager, and the platform verifies ok; however, in project properties>Run>Runtime platform, the only option listed is "project platform", despite that fact that when I click "manage platform" next to it, my platform shows up fine.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I have a feeling something might be misconfigured, or maybe I'm using the wrong type of project or something, but notihng I try seems to work. The project is just a simple java application (created with new project>java>java application), and I am using the latest version of Raspian on the Pi, with the preloaded java installation, located at /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/jre.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday, and I solve it!

Main reason is: you need the **same JDK** for NetBeans and Raspberry.

I use Raspberry PI 3+ (64 bit) with Debian OS (32 bit), JDK 8 has support for ARM 32 bit, I downloaded the last version: "jdk-8u271-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz".
https://www.oracle.com/it/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

Unfortunately, JDK 15 hasen't the 32 bit ARM version...

I also installed the JDK 8 in Windows with NetBeans: "jdk-8u271-windows-x64" and then, you need to change the default JDK in the .conf NetBeans file.
https://www.codejava.net/ides/netbeans/change-jdk-for-netbeans

Now, when you open *Properties/run/* you can select the remote platform.

Enjoy,
Best Regards.

Marco